# Does WPF use the installed color profile(ICC) in windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, color-management

Does WPF use the installed color profile in windows for correcting the colors that are rendered?

I'm pretty sure old forms/gdi-based applications are not "automatically" color corrected, but I wonder if WPF does (or can be made to do) this automatically?
(I know I can do this manually in my own WPF apps by creating a gpu shader to do the color correction.)

The reason I ask is because more and more monitors are now wide gamut, this means that colors that look "normal" on "old" monitors will seem much more vibrant on wide gamut monitors. An example is my new monitor which has much stronger red and green colors than my other monitors. 
I can correct this problem on a per-application basis for some applications (firefox, photoshop, media players using a custom shader etc.., my own wpf apps using gpu shaders..) but it would be nice if there was a way to have WPF do it automatically for all WPF applications.
It is not a big problem but it is however annoying and I had hoped that Microsoft would take the opportunity with WPF to introduce color correction by default.

edit: question clarified for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  You have to implement it yourself in your app.  Just like the the old forms/gdi apps.

I think this is a pretty big problem!  The only application I have which supports color profiles is photoshop and I'm hardly use that.  In all other situations my new wide gamut display is much worse than the sRGB one it replaced.

At a 92% gamut the colors were a little over saturated, but displays keep pushing this up and are at 110%+ now.  The farther they push this the worse these displays get in non managed apps.  Since there are almost no managed apps then most of the the time these displays are very bad.

Each app impelmenting color management support does not seem realistic.  This needs to be done on an OS or driver level.  You mention that you can do this with GPU shaders, but I know of nobody doing that except for an unofficial plugin to an open source media player.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is very unfortunate. I had hoped that WPF would take the opportunity to enable color correction by default.

Answer (score 0):

Color correction can be enabled with the Nuget package Mscms.WPF.
It's free for non-commercial use. The commercial version is also GPU accelerated and offers more features.